# Sharing Folder with Jenkins Slave in Workflow Script

Tags: jenkins, virtualbox, jenkins-workflow

I'm having some problems accessing a shared folder between an OS X Jenkins master and a Windows VM slave.

- The set-up is an OS X host running Jenkins and using VirtualBox to host a Windows VM slave.
- The Jenkins slave is running as a Windows service with auto-logon as a Jenkins Slave user.
- Via VirtualBox a shared folder has been set-up between the two mapped to drive E: on the Windows slave.

From the master I'm trying to execute a batch script in the shared folder on the slave in a groovy Workflow script.

```
node("Windows") {
    bat("E:\\some\\path\\thingy.bat")
}
```

When I try and run this I get `The system cannot find the drive specified.`

If I log into the slave VM as the Jenkins Slave user and try to do the same everything works.

I've confirmed that from within the workflow script I am running as the same Jenkins Slave user but for some reason the E: drive that represents the shared folder isn't visible.

Can anyone shed any light on what the problem may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer was to use a UNC path.

When I tried this before I was only specifying the server name not the name of the shared folder itself.

So if your shared folder is called "shared" then

```
\\VBOXSVR\ (Doesn't work)
\\VBOXSVR\shared (Does work)
```

Bit of a silly mistake but there you go.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using a UNC path?

Did you check that `\` is properly escaped in the Groovy string?

Is the slave root on `E:` or `C:`?

Comment: I tried UNC but I get the message that the server isn't recognized and I checked the slashes are properly escaped. The share between the slave and master is E: